# Multi-character column delimiter not supported in ADF connection

Tags: azure-data-factory

My text file has a delimiter with 2 characters (`~*`).

However ADF supports column delimiters with only one chararacter. Any help or workaround?

It is a text file present in Azure blob storage which needs to be imported to SQL database.

[image: Screenshot here]

Answer (score 1):

**As of Dec 4th 2021, ADF now has the option for a multiple character delimiter on a copy data activity:**

[image: ADF Enhancement]

See below example for where delimiter goes:

[image: Dataset Example CSV]

Comment: Oh good news @TrentTamura and welcome back!

Answer (score 0):

One workaround would be to go with U-SQL scripts, there you can use any delimiter, I usually prefer non-printable characters like "\u0001", for instance I use this as a column delimiter in most of my Azure Data Analytics U-SQL Scripts, and you can run the U-SQL script from ADF.

### Update

I ended up using the Start of Heading character (`\u0001`), in fact it is one of the options available in the UI and it's been working so far, there are still some bugs with other delimiters like ('¬') but MS is working on that.

[image]